# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in xcode trying to call a method from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I run into EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my code,

I'm trying to run a method in class PurchaseTowerMenuLayer, 
method is from class UnitDatabase:

PurchaseTowerMenuLayer.m:

```
delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// getUnitDatabase returns UnitDatabase class from GameScene class

[[[delegate getGameScene] getUnitDatabase] createUnit:@"t01"]; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here
```

UnitDatabase.m:

```
-(void)createUnit:(NSString *)unitID
{

typeString = [unitID substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
numberString = [unitID substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,2)];

Unit *unit;

if(unitID == @"t00")
    [unit setUnitID:unitID];

etc...
}
```

What am I doing to get this error? How should it look like?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated;  don't prefix methods with "get".   `get` is reserved for a very specific roll.  This isn't it.  Just name 'em `unitDatabase` and `gameScene`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, first separate the call `[[[delegate getGameScene] getUnitDatabase] createUnit:@"t01"];` for three lines such as

```
GameScene* scene = [delegate getGameScene];
UnitDatabase* unitDatabase = [scene getUnitDatabase];
[unitDatabase createUnit:@"t01"];
```

This'll allow you to pinpoint which call emits the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and you can collapse them back after if you prefer.

After you identified which line emits the error, it's usually a matter of finding where you haven't called `[[MyClass alloc] init];`.  For example, if `getGameScene` or `getUnitDatabase` return objects that weren't `alloc`'d/`init`'d (or `delegate` too for that matter), then you want to make sure to do that at least before you return them.

I can't help much more without seeing more code but these errors often go like this.  Make sure you alloc and initialize the objects you keep as members of other objects.

Comment: I didn't alloc - initialize UnitDatabase, thanks pwny! and Unit too wasnt alloc inited as Sean pointed below.

Comment: No problem, good luck with whatever you're doing.  iOS is rough sometimes but very rewarding :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't allocated or initialized `unit`. Try changing `Unit *unit;` to:

`Unit *unit = [[Unit alloc] init];`

Add, of course make sure to release/autorelease if you're not using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Also, as a future reference, whenever you run into something like try, try to identify the specific line of code that gives you the error. I this case I am pretty sure it is not your `PurchaseTowerMenuLayer.m` that's being problematic - it's something inside the `createUnit` method. Even that will probably not be accurate enough - it might be a system call ten levels deep. You should try to identify things like that before asking for help - it will, in many cases, help you get to the answer yourself. And sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your scheme and enable NSZombie for more explicit errors